# In Telerik radrotator(legand) date is binding as system.byte

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

In Telerik `radrotator(legand)` date is binding as `system.byte`:

```
Dim mssQL=" case when a.log_type='Schedule' then" & _
          " (select case when e.schedule_type='Call Log' then cast( concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled a Call On',' ',(DATE_FORMAT(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y') ) ) as char )" & _
          " when e.schedule_type='Meeting' then cast(concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled a Meeting  On', ' ',(DATE_FORMAT(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y') )) as char )" & _
          " when e.schedule_type='Mail Log' then cast (concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled Mail On',' ',(DATE_FORMAT(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y'))) as char) end  from crm_trn_tschedulelog e where e.log_gid=a.log_gid group by a.log_gid)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `CAST()` and `concat()` functions. The `concat()` will give you result as `system.byte` when the input parameters to the function are of different types, here you are concatenating string and DATE Together. you you need to cast the Formatted Date also and remove the cast before the `Concat()`. Hence your query will be like the following:

```
 concat(d.user_firstname,' ',d.user_lastname,' ','Scheduled Mail On',' ',cast (DATE_FORMAT(e.schedule_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as char)))
```